# How to Update Table1 two columns from another table select query in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am new in MSSQL  Server so in oracle we can update one table from another table select as per below so how can 
i do same operation in sql server.

```
    UPDATE table1
    SET (col1, col2) = (SELECT col1, col2
                          FROM table2
                         WHERE table2.ID = table1.ID)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

> ```
> UPDATE
> Table1 
> SET Table1.col1 = Table2.col1,
>     Table1.col2 = Table2.col2 
> FROM
> Table1 
> INNER JOIN Table2 
> ON Table1.id = Table2.id
> ```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE t1
SET t1.dcamt1 = t2.ecamt1
FROM pgptrans t1
INNER JOIN pgptrans060713 t2 ON t1.empcode = t2.empcode
WHERE t1.empcode LIKE '130%' 
    AND t1.yrmn = '201308' 
    AND t2.yrmn = '201207'

Try this